# JavaEE CDI and JAXRS injecting into @Provider gives UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, cdi

I have a JAXRS provider:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Inject
    private AuthSecurityContext authSecurityContext;

    // ...

}
```

And my SecurityContext implementation:

```
@RequestScoped
public class AuthSecurityContext implements SecurityContext {

    // ...

}
```

I'm using glassfish as my container but it's throwing the following exception:

```
2017-06-26T01:04:49.139+0100|Warning: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 1
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=AuthSecurityContext,parent=AuthFilter,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,2049394753)
```

My other beans are being discovered and injected but this one in the `@Provider` doesn't work, what am I missing?

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: Be sure you are using the `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped` and not `javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped`

Comment: @Rouliboy I'm using Glassfish 4.1 as the container.

Comment: @maress Yes I was using `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`.

Comment: In fact adding the `javax.enterprise.context.Dependent` annotation to `AuthFilter` seemed to make it work although I'm not exactly sure what this does other than telling CDI (HK2 in this case) that it is a managed object, is this correct?

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that in my beans.xml I have `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"` which is probably why the AuthFilter provider wasn't found without a CDI specific annotation, without the `@Dependent` annotation it would work if I had `bean-discovery-mode="all"`. I'm not 100% sure on my explaination if someone could explain all this in an answer I'd accept it, or if someone could confirm what I'm saying is correct then I can write the answer.

Comment: You are correct  ;-)

Comment: I'll go with that then, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand the problem was that I had `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"` in my beans.xml, JAX-RS annotated classes are not automatically managed by the container's CDI implementation, therefore there was two possible solutions:

Set `bean-discovery-mode="all"`

OR

Adding the `javax.enterprise.context.Dependent` annotation to AuthFilter to let the CDI know that it is a managed object.